# Call function when adding a div to my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a script which adds a div to my site when I upload a photo. Now I wan't to call a function when this div gets added. I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
var divImg = document.createElement("div");
divImg.id = "divimg";
newImg.setAttribute('onload','urediBtnx(this)');
divImg.innerHTML = '<a href=""><img src="/imago/images/btnx.gif" class="btnx"></a>';
```

It should call this function:

```
function urediBtnx(dv){
    alert("blabla");
}
```

The thing is, if I do it this way, then the function gets called, but I need to get the div, not the img.

```
divImg.innerHTML = '<a href=""><img onload="urediBtnx(this)" src="/imago/images/btnx.gif" class="btnx"></a>';
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need it on the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach onload event handlers to element like body, img, script or iframe, but not to a div.

In your scenario, the div is the grand-parent of your image. You can keep the onload on the image, then use this.parentNode.parentNode to reach the div.

Comment: I've tried this one before but this way: dv.parentNode.id and now I see what I did wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, `<div>`'s don't have an `onload` because they don't get loaded.  Documents are loaded, images are loaded, iframes are loaded - divs just are.  To achieve what you want, you should just call `urediBtnx()` immediately from the same code where you call `appendChild()` to insert the div into the document, because at that point, the div is as "loaded" as it's going to get. (If you change the contents of the div later, you may need to call the function again from that code...)

Comment: And once again the Downvote Ninja has downvoted one of my answers without any explanatory comment...

Answer (score 0):

Div does not have an onload event. They are only availabe for `<body>`, `<frame>`, `<frameset>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<link>` or `<script>`.

Subsequently calling the function after its added to the DOM is a way.

```
parent.appendChild(divImg);
urediBtnx();
```

The possibility of a callback can be gained if you are jQuery library

```
$("#parent").append($(divImg), function() {
    urediBtnx();
});
```